# Adding Bootstrap img-responsive class to Wordpress images fails at gallery thumbs

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, gallery

I'm working on a Bootstrap 3 Wordpress theme. To make my images responsive I added Bootstrap's img-responsive class to them with the following code in my functions.php

```html
<?php 
 
   function bootstrap_responsive_images( $html ){
  $classes = 'img-responsive'; // separated by spaces, e.g. 'img image-link'

  // check if there are already classes assigned to the anchor
  if ( preg_match('/<img.*? class="/', $html) ) {
    $html = preg_replace('/(<img.*? class=".*?)(".*?\/>)/', '$1 ' . $classes . ' $2', $html);
  } else {
    $html = preg_replace('/(<img.*?)(\/>)/', '$1 class="' . $classes . '" $2', $html);
  }
  // remove dimensions from images,, does not need it!
  $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
  return $html;
}
add_filter( 'the_content','bootstrap_responsive_images',10 );
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'bootstrap_responsive_images', 10 );
```

This works pretty well, all  get their class="img-responsive" except the thumbs in galleries. They only hav class="attachment-thumbnail or attachment-medium" depending on te choosen image size.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same CSS bootstrap uses for .img-responsive and create a selector for your image galleries and apply that CSS to your new selector